# Checking to see if an optional protocol method has been implemented

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols

Does anyone know the best way to check to see if an optional protocol method has been implemented.

I tried this:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(optionalProtocolMethod:)] )
```

where delegate is:

```
id<MyProtocol> delegate;
```

However, I get an error saying that the function `respondsToSelector:` is not found in the protocol!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`respondsToSelector:` is part of the `NSObject` protocol. Including `NSObject` in `MyProtocol` should solve your problem:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)optionalProtocolMethod:(id)anObject;

@end
```

Comment: Except you're not supposed to retain your delegates, so why are you calling [delegate release]?

Comment: To be fair to grilix there are situations where a delegate must be retained.

Comment: @MikeWeller Curious about use cases for retaining the delegate. Any examples of why you would do this?

Answer (score 5):

What I do is applying the following recipe:

```
if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(closed)]){
    [self.delegate closed];
}
```

Where 'closed' is the method that I wanted to call.

Comment: Does that a overkill? If delegate doesn't exist. [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(closed)] will return nil.